# GPS: в чём измеряются получаемые данные о высоте со спутника?

Tags: android, gps

В чём измеряются получаемые данные о высоте со спутника?

Comment: В попугаях... Если серьезно, то зависит от API, может в метрах, сантиметрах, футах или ярдах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Читаем доки андроида -> [GetAltitude](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getAltitude()). Там сказано что в метрах над уровнем моря

```
public double getAltitude ()
Added in API level 1
Get the altitude if available, in meters above sea level.
If this location does not have an altitude then 0.0 is returned.
```